# PHP : Download a file in excel format

Tags: php, excel

I am using these headers to , trigger a download for excel file ;

my code is

```
 <?php 
 header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.xls"');
 echo 'name \t age \t city';
  ?>
```

This code triggers a download . but when i try to open the file it says

> Microsoft Excel viewer can not open files of these types

I just want to export(output) 10 rows , So i don't want to use any library , is their any way to download an excel file , without using any library

help please

Comment: Nothing was working , So i downloaded PHPEXCEL library , and refer to this link http://tutsheap.com/web/create-and-download-excel-file-using-php/   Working like a charm

Answer (score 1):

try to change file extension to xlsx and make sure that you are using double quotes when echoing invisible characters like \t

Answer (score 0):

Think your tab character is wrong way round:

```
 echo 'name\t age \t city';
```

Comment: updated my question, it was a typo, in real code i am using \t, do u have another suggestions  thanks

Comment: i think i have to use a library,